# Memory leak in Python Flask when using tensorflow.keras.models.load_model to predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, memory-leaks

I have a flask application that has a memory leak and I am unable to figure out where I'm going wrong. I create a flask app and use tensorflow.keras.models.load_model to predict. And I call this Web-API per 100ms. Memory increases over time. The memory leak is happened...

I have read many threads on StackOverflow about the same issue, but I couldn't find any solutions to my problem.

Here's what my Flask app looks like:

```
#%% import
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from flask import Flask, request
from tensorflow import convert_to_tensor
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import gc

APP = Flask(__name__)

#%% Function
@APP.route('/app')
def app():
    ## load model
    model = load_model('model.h5', compile = False)
    
    ## input parameter
    p1 = float(request.args.get('p1')).astype('float32')
    p2 = float(request.args.get('p2')).astype('float32')
    
    ## combine parameter
    p = np.zeros((1, 2))
    p[0,1] = p1
    p[0,2] = p2
    
    ## predicted
    predicted = model(convert_to_tensor(p))
    K.clear_session()
    
    ## clear
    gc.collect()
    model = None
    del model, p
    
    return str(predicted)
    
#%% main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP.run(debug = False, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 12345)
```

Environment：

1. Python 3.10
2. Flask 2.3.3
3. tensorflow 2.13.0

Could you please tell me if it really is a memory leak issue? What additional steps could be taken to fix it? Any help would be very much appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: I also had the same issue few days back. I used docker images and downgraded from TF 2.13 to tensorflow/tensorflow:2.10.0-gpu and used ENV TF_RUN_EAGER_OP_AS_FUNCTION=0 flag in my docker file. Now its working fine. I found this issue in [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58676)